# Need to find and delete the duplicates records from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to delete the duplicates from my employee table but if the duplicates occurs in same company name it should be retained.

I have following data

```
    empid       resource        Dpart        company
   111          alex             AA            1C
   112          chris            QA            2F
   111          alex             AA            1C 
   111          alex             AA            2F
   111          alex             AA            2F
   111          alex             AA            5F
```

I have tried the row_number() over(partition) but does't give what i expected. pls help us.

```
 delete  duplicates from (SELECT empid, 
 resouces,department ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY  empid, 
 resouces,departmentORDER BY empid) cnt FROM 
 (select empid, resouces,department from Employee )t1)  
 duplicates    WHERE duplicates.Cnt > 1
```

From the above data after duplicate deletion the Employee Table should have

```
   empid       resource        Dpart        company
   111          alex             AA            1C
   112          chris            QA            2F
   111          alex             AA            1C
```

Comment: what result does your query give currently?

Comment: does the result table should have the two rows with (111,alex,AA,2F)? this row is duplicated in same company name

Comment: The result table you have mentioned does have duplicates. You might want to look at something like this "select empid, resource, dpart, max(company) from Employee group by empid, resource, dpart" if you are looking at getting one results per empid, resource, dpart.

Comment: Currently it does't retain the duplicates occurs in same company name.

Comment: Do you really want to delete *all* rows with `(111,alex,AA,2F)`? Your desired results contain duplicates too

Comment: what do you mean by duplicates occur for the same company then retain can you tell me why only the duplicate of 1C you have retained why not 2F for employee 111. thats not the question exactly thats made a question to seek attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `DENSE_RANK()` instead :

```
DELETE e
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY empid, resource, Dpart ORDER BY company) AS Seq
      FROM Employee e
     ) e
WHERE e.Seq > 1;
```

Comment: . . .  You should accept @ZaynulAbadinTuhin solution as he gave the solution before this one, i just never seen before i posted & added the more `keys` in `partition` clause.

Answer (score 0):

use `dense_rank`

```
with cte as
(
select *,dense_rank() over(partition by empid order by company) as rn
from Employee
)delete from cte where rn>1
```

[Demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=daf67232b3b2dca2e590d4a85be8a69f)

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example below:

-- create table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DiaChiEmail(
ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Email VARCHAR(100),
Ten NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO
```

-- insert some records

```
INSERT dbo.DiaChiEmail(Email,Ten)
 SELECT 'abc@gmail.com', 'abc' UNION ALL -- #1
 SELECT 'def@yahoo.com', 'def' UNION ALL -- #2
 SELECT 'ghi@hotmail.com', 'ghi' UNION ALL -- #3
 SELECT 'jkl@ymail.com', 'jkl' UNION ALL -- #4
 SELECT 'abc@gmail.com', 'abc 2' UNION ALL -- #5, dupl with #1
 SELECT 'abc@gmail.com', 'abc 3' UNION ALL -- #6, dupl with #1
 SELECT 'ghi@hotmail.com', 'ghi 2' -- #7, dupl with ghi #3
```

And the query to remove duplicates records is:

```
WITH [TBL_DUPLICATE] AS
(
  SELECT
   STT = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY ID DESC), Email
   FROM DiaChiEmail
    )
DELETE FROM [TBL_DUPLICATE] WHERE STT > 1
```